# How to create the code behind of Razor page

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, code-behind, razor-pages

When I create a new Razor page in **Visual Studio 2017**, the separated code behind file did not get created.

This is the screenshot of the problem highlighted.

[image]

We can see the Razor page called `List.cshtml` does not contain the code behind file. Contrast that with the default page `about.cshtml`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 - Right click on "resturants", add class:

2 - in your case, call it List.cshtml.cs. This will create the code behind. It nows needs wiring up. Open the class that has been created.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//Add the MVC usings
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

//TODO The namespace will be correct in your code
namespace app_name.Pages.resturants
{
    //public class List
    //TODO correct the model name and inherit PageModel
    public List1Model : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

3 - In List.cshtml:

```
@page
@model app_name.Pages.resturants.List1Model
@{
}
```

More information can be found here on modifying the code behind https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 supports grouping of files when your razor page as the name `Page1.razor` you can add css, cs and js grouped files files, when you call them `Page1.razor.css`, `Page1.razor.ss` or `Page1.razor.js`

Comment: but when you paste a razor and razor.cs into the folder visual studio does not understand that they should be linked?